# Plot lines between points using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, ios7.1

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this thing out, I want the user to tap once in a location, then tap in another location and have a line, curve or arc drawn between the points. How would you approach this, I'm very new to iOS and the documentation isn't helping. I implemented the following method in the view controller:

```
- (IBAction)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint currentPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring out where to go from here, what to do. I created a UIView subclass containing the drawRect method, but I have no idea what to do there, I know that the drawRect method is to draw the shape, but using tap recognizer I don't know how to implement something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the view that will draw, you need to create two properties:

```
@property CGPoint firstPoint;
@property CGPoint secondPoint;
```

Besides, you have to create the `drawRect:` method. The example draws a line between both points:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{ 
    // Color Declarations
    UIColor *lineColor = [UIColor colorForString:@"appBlack"];
    // Line between the two touches in screen
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:firstPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:secondPoint];
    //Sets line width and color
    [lineColor setStroke];
    [path setLineWidth:1.];
    //Draws the line
    [path stroke];
}
```

This is a very basic implementation, you should check whether firstPoint and secondPoint are defined to actually perform the drawing.

Finally, when the user taps the screen, and the app calls

```
- (IBAction)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
```

you set the points to your view and then if it is the second time, repaint the view.

I will suppose you are drawing in a view that is a property of your ViewController:

```
 @property UIView myView;
```

where you defined your `singleTap:` method:

```
- (IBAction)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    CGPoint currentPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    if(first_time_called){
        self.myView.firstPoint = currentPoint;
    }
    else{
        self.myView.secondPoint = currentPoint;
        [self.myView setNeedsDisplay]; //forces the repainting of the view
    }
}
```

Take into account that you have to create the condition: first_time_called.

Also you have to be aware that if myView and the view property of your ViewController do not have the same frame you will have to translate the point to myView using:

```
convertPoint:fromView:
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to add the CGPoint properties again in ViewController (where I have the IBAction method). myView gives me an error, if I change it to view or self.view it still gives me an error. Do you know why?